# Windows form keeps re-sizing itself in design mode after running debugger

Tags: winforms, window-resize

I have a windows form that keeps resizing itself in design mode after running the debugger. Before running my application, I've checked the size of the form in question and everything looks perfect. Then when I run the program, exit, and look at the form in the designer, the form has automatically shrunk itself...in the designer. It isn't a huge difference, but it's enough to irk the ever-living crap out of me as panel borders get cut off when this happens and it just looks bad.

Does anyone have any ideas on what may be causing this? It's not autoscroll, and the form is double buffered with a fixedsingle border. It's also locked, and the size of the form is definitely not larger than my screen. There doesn't seem to be much of a pattern to when this happens. Sometimes when I run my program, it doesn't resize itself, other times it does...but again, it's resizing itself in the designer which I find pretty weird. Would love to hear some thoughts on what I may be overlooking.

Comment: I am having a resize issue that only seems to happen when `ControlBox = False`